# QLDB gives OCC on a read only transaction?

Tags: amazon-qldb

I know that QLDB uses OCC and I understand that there are serialization requirements around updates. However, under heavy load I've noticed OCCs occurring for, what I strongly suspect are, read only requests.

Is this expected? Using the Java drivers is there a way to mark a transaction is read only OR allow read-committed data but and not throw a OCC is a document is changed?